# Ruby syntax fat arrow

Tags: ruby

I'm struggling to learn Ruby.  I don't understand what the last line of this function is doing, specifically the fat arrow =>. Is the symbol :word doing something to the variable masquerade_word, or vice versa, is it an assignment?. Also, I'm confused, is the symbol `:word` the same as `session[:word]`.     Can anyone please clarify ...

```
post "/new" do
  word = Word.get_random
  masquerade_word = Word.masquerade(word)

  session[:word] = word
  session[:incorrect_guesses] = 0
  session[:chars_left] = word.size
  session[:revealed_word] = masquerade_word

  {:word => masquerade_word}.to_json
end
```

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I left a similar comment like yours a while ago. How come it changed to yours? Just wondering.

Comment: @sawa There were no other comments when I posted mine.

Comment: actually i know what a hash is from having read a ruby book, but I got confused for a couple reasons. One, I usually see them assigned to a variable. Two, I didn't understand why create a hash with only one key/value (usually see them with more), so the code just looked different from the context I was used to seeing it. Also on top of that confusion, naming the key :word confused me because there was a session[:word] as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way of defining a hash.

It is the same as `Hash(:word, masquerade_word)`

The key is `:word` and the value is `masquerade_word`

Comment: thanks, so if masquerade_word is "albania", after it runs through to_json it will be {"word" : "albania"} ?